# Is it possible to prevent thisd-party js-snippets ("widgets") from setting cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, widget

For easy implementation of third-party features (i think sometimes called "widgets"), you often get a javascript-snippet to implement on your website. When your website is opened in the browser HTML-content gets rendered from the js and also often a cookie will be set.

Can you somehow prevent the setting of a cookie (in most cases it is not necessary, just for tracking…)?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change or modify cookies that have been set by the third-party scripts if they were loaded from a different domain.

> Blockquote By default, a cookie is accessible only at the domain that set it. So, if the cookie was set by site.com, we won’t get it other.com.

> Blockquote …But what’s more tricky, we also won’t get the cookie at a subdomain forum.site.com!

See this for more information: [javascript.info ::: Cookies, document.cookie](https://javascript.info/cookie#domain)